# How to cast an numpy ndarray from f_style to c_style in pybind11?

Tags: numpy-ndarray, pybind11

I'm writing a python library with `pybind11` in c++. The library accepts as input a vari-dim numpy ndarray of any data type. But as mentioned in numpy's documentation, `ndarray` can be continuous or not, and may have row-major (c-style) or column-major (f-style) layout, so as to `pybind11::array_t` and `pybind11::array`. So I've to cast input ndarray(specifically `pybind11::array` in my case) into continuous row-major format before feeding into my core logic.
But after digging in `pybind11`'s doc and source code, I found no straightforward way to do it. But there's a [`copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method in numpy's python interface to do so.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just feature out it's possible to call python method, see: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/utilities.html#using-python-s-print-function-in-c .